# Why they normalize dictionary atoms instead of L2-regularization in the objective?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regularization, constraint-programming

I noticed in the dictionary learning when we have a typical optimization problem like: 
$$\min_D \|Y-DX\|_2^2  $$
$Y$ is the matrix of the data samples and $X$ is the matrix of encoded vectors for the data (sparse codes).

they usually normalize the columns of the dictionary atoms at the end or during the optimization steps (ex. projected-GD), so they would have L2-norm equal to 1 like having it as a constraint:
$$s.t~~~\|d_i\|_2^2=1$$
For example in the paper [Online Learning for Matrix Factorization and Sparse Coding](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0050).
But i noticed the result after this manual normalization (hard-constraint) could be sub-optimal.

my question is why don't they add a regularization term to the objective function like this:
$$\min_D \|Y-DX\|_2^2  + \lambda \|D\|_F^2$$ 
would it force the norm-2 of dictionary columns to be limited and more or less in a similar range? In that case think the benefit is the that the optimum point would be found systematically and we can assume or check the optimal conditions for that point.

Please let me know if i'm right or wrong about this.

Comment: Can you give a reference that you've been looking at that says you should normalize the columns of the dictionary atoms during the optimization steps?

Comment: So $D$ is supposed to be the dictionary? Well what properties should a dictionary have? You will need to explain more carefully what the variables mean if people are to understand.

Comment: for example this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0050

Comment: Sapiro rings a bell. I don't remember from his talks if they had some iterative procedure for sparseness. Well to achieve true sparseness for a linear system one would need some iterative scheme to push harder and harder towards 0, since the 2 norm is not really suitable. Maybe replace $\lambda$ by a diagonal matrix that pushes harder towards 0 the closer we already are to 0. Or to aim for a 1 norm with a convex method or something else.

Comment: Usually Sparse Coding involves $ {L}_{1} $ norm. Where did you see in the paper what you described (Page, Equation)?

Comment: I second @Royi's request for the page number and equation number where these optimization problems occur, because I think they have not been described correctly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

From algorithm 1 and 2 from the paper you referred to, they are solving a Lasso type problem. If you don't normalize your dictionary, the $\ell_1$-penalty will perform really badly. For instance, consider the following Lasso problem
$$
\underset{x}{\text{minimize}}\quad \frac{1}{2}||y-Dx||_2^2+\lambda||x||_1
$$
where the columns of $D$ contains, let say, different sequences of lengths. If one column is measured in meters and another column in micro meters, your $x$ variable will be dependent on the unit of the columns of $D$. Since your sparsifying penalty does not take this imbalance into consideration, you will probably get a solution that sets the element in $x$ that corresponds to the column in $D$ that is measured in meters to zero, even though it actually might explain much of the signal.

I don't know if I answered your question, or if I justed stated the obvious. If so - sorry!

Comment: You answered a part of my question about the reason they like to normalize columns of $D$, but it is a hard limit and makes the optimization sub-optimal. But my main question is what if we add the 2-norm of D in the objective instead of having a hard limit on the solution, would it do a similar thing?

Comment: It would help, but it does not guarantee that $D$ is in $\mathcal{C}$ as defined under equation $(2)$ in the paper you referred to.